# Why is toList (1, 2) == [2]

Tags: haskell

As the question says, why is `toList (1, 2) == [2]`?

I remember something similar happening when fmapping on tuples, but I do not remember why or if it is related.

Comment: Waah, length (1, 2) is 1.

Comment: Why not? What would you expect?

Comment: In [1]: len((1, 2))
Out[1]: 2

Comment: As to the why: it's because `Foldable` on tuples is basically only looking at the last component of the tuple and ignores all other

Comment: it's more or less this: `instance Foldable ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
` ... you (and many other) might disagree about this definition but it's useful in some cases and you are free to ignore it if you like

Comment: @zakyggaps I'd rather say it's the bad side of defining all those functor instances for tuples (as well as, with similar problems, functions). I tend to think it would have been better to leave that to the far more descriptive equivalents `Writer` / `Reader`, where the behaviour wouldn't surprise anybody, and only make `(,)` and `(->)` instances of `Bifunctor` and `Arrow`, respectively.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`(1,2)` does not correspend to the list `[1,2]`. That wouldn't make sense: what would then `(True, 3.14)` correspend to? You can't have the list `[True, 3.14]`, because a list can only contain elements of a single type. (Haskell is different from e.g. Python here.)

The only way to pick elements of guaranteed a single type from any tuple is, well, *to take only a single element*. Hence `toList`, as generated from the `Foldable (a,)` instance, takes tuples `(a,b)` and yields lists `[b]`. Obviously there's always exactly one `b` element in such a tuple<sup>†</sup>.

You could in principle consider `(Int, Int)` as a special case where the elements have the same type and hence you can pick two instead of one, but such a special handling would require some highly awkward type-equality checking. And generally, special-case handling is not a good idea.

Arguably, it would have been better not to define the `Foldable (a,)` instance at all, to avoid this confusing behaviour. Then again, sometimes it's handy to use `fold` to just get rid of the first tuple element (e.g. some index).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Why use `b` and not `a`? Kind of arbitrary? Well, not completely. `(a,b)` is actually syntactic sugar for `(,) a b`, hence you can consider `(,) a` as a functor (whose elements have type `b`), but you can't have a functor `` (`(,)`b) `` whose elements would have type `a`.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

If you are planning to use homogeneous pairs heavily, you may want to declare  a new type which will precisely correspond to them. This way you'll be able to have access to the `toList` you were expecting.

```
newtype Pair a = Pair { pair :: (a, a) }

instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair (x, y)) = Pair (f x, f y)

instance Foldable Pair where
  foldr f z (Pair (x, y)) = f x $ f y z
```

`(a, b)` is fundamentally different from `Pair a` or `Constant (a, a) b` and it is important to clearly document which one you mean in your code if you want typeclass resolution to pick the right instance.

```
newtype Constant a b = Constant a

instance Functor (Constant a) where
  fmap f (Constant a) = Constant a

instance Foldable (Constant a) where
  foldr f z _ = z
```

Examples:

```
length (Constant (1, 2)) == 0
length (1, 2)            == 1
length (Pair (1, 2))     == 2
```

Answer (score 4):

The results do make more sense when you interpret the function names like this:

`length` - how many values will be touched by `fmap`, `fold` etc.

`toList` - what elements will be touched by `fmap`, `fold` etc.

As long as

```
length x == length (toList x)
```

the world is fine.