# How to construct an array with multiple possible lengths using immutability and functional programming practices?

Tags: haskell, typescript, functional-programming, immutability, elm

We're in the process of converting our imperative brains to a mostly-functional paradigm.  This function is giving me trouble. I want to construct an array that EITHER contains two pairs or three pairs, depending on a condition (whether `refreshToken` is `null`).  How can I do this cleanly using a FP paradigm?  Of course with imperative code and mutation, I would just conditionally `.push()` the extra value onto the end which looks quite clean.

Is this an example of the "local mutation is ok" FP caveat?

(We're using `ReadonlyArray` in TypeScript to enforce immutability, which makes this somewhat more ugly.)

```
const itemsToSet = [
    [JWT_KEY, jwt],
    [JWT_EXPIRES_KEY, tokenExpireDate.toString()],
    [REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY, refreshToken /*could be null*/]]
    .filter(item => item[1] != null) as ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<string>>;

AsyncStorage.multiSet(itemsToSet.map(roArray => [...roArray]));
```

Comment: Your solution seems perfectly reasonable, and performance is likely not a concern for three element arrays. I would argue there is no local mutation here; you cannot refer to the original array which is mutated, so there is no way to observe mutation even if it does occur (a compiler could chose to optimize away the construction of the initial array precisely because there is no possible way to refer to it). Even in Haskell, the runtime can update a value in place if it is used in precisely one place. The takeaway is that "mutation" = "observable mutation", i.e. "local mutation is ok".

Comment: This is JavaScript. Just use `.push`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with `itemsToSet` as given in the OP? It looks functional to me, but it may be because of my lack of knowledge of TypeScript.

In Haskell, there's no *null*, but if we use `Maybe` for the second element, I think that `itemsToSet` could be translated to this:

```
itemsToSet :: [(String, String)]
itemsToSet = foldr folder [] values
  where
    values = [
      (jwt_key, jwt),
      (jwt_expires_key, tokenExpireDate),
      (refresh_token_key, refreshToken)]
    folder (key, Just value) acc = (key, value) : acc
    folder _ acc = acc
```

Here, `jwt`, `tokenExpireDate`, and `refreshToken` are all of the type `Maybe String`.

`itemsToSet` performs a *right fold* over `values`, pattern-matching the `Maye String` elements against `Just` and (implicitly) `Nothing`. If it's a `Just` value, it cons the `(key, value)` pair to the accumulator `acc`. If not, `folder` just returns `acc`.

`foldr` traverses the `values` list from right to left, building up the accumulator as it visits each element. The initial accumulator value is the empty list `[]`.

You don't need 'local mutation' in functional programming. In general, you can refactor from 'local mutation' to proper functional style by [using recursion and introducing an accumulator value](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/01/recurse).

While `foldr` is a built-in function, you could implement it yourself using recursion.

Comment: `itemsToSet = catMaybes $ fmap sequenceA values` ;)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Amazing; 20 minutes later, I think that I _almost_ understand that :|

Comment: Haha! Sorry. Didn't intend to drop a brain-bomb on you! Briefly: `sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)` is a general tool to transpose two constructors. Here `f ~ Maybe` and `t ~ (,) String`, so **`sequenceA :: (String, Maybe String) -> Maybe (String, String)`**. If we had `t ~ []`, `sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]` would sequence _many_ effects to produce a list of results. Here there's only _one_ effect: the "container" type is the tuple and it "contains" its second element. Then `catMaybes` just filters out the `Nothing`s. Hope that explains it! :)

Comment: If that still doesn't make sense, feel free to ask another question and I'll try to explain in more depth in an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks :) What really threw me is that `(,)` is `Foldable`. Hardly intuitive, if you ask me, but I found an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36461185/126014

Comment: Yep, the `Foldable`/`Traversable` instances for `(,) x` in particular have proven to be quite controversial over the years. I can see both sides of the argument: they do frequently cause learners to trip up, but they're _so useful_ once you're familiar with `Foldable` and `Traversable`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson BTW, my primary motivation for starting to answer Haskell questions here on SO is an attempt to improve my Haskell skills. Those gems of yours certainly challenges me, so keep them coming :)

Comment: Next time I'll be sure to explain myself :)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson No, please don't! I learn more by trying to puzzle those things together for myself :)

Comment: Haha, OK then! Always happy to help out if you get stuck though (and my email address is in my profile) :D

Comment: Really helpful, thank you Mark.  I'm using an accumulator-style implementation, and it's a good reminder that we can look to recursive implementations in other cases (still overcoming lifetime of OO- and mutable-style thinking). 

Gave it a try, but not ready for the @BenjaminHodgson kung fu yet!

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, I'd just create an array with three elements and, depending on the condition, pass it on either as-is or pass on just a slice of two elements. Thanks to laziness, no computation effort will be spent on the third element unless it's actually needed. In TypeScript, you probably will get the cost of computing the third element even if it's not needed, but perhaps that doesn't matter.

Alternatively, if you don't need the structure to be an actual array (for `String` elements, performance probably isn't that critical, and the *O* (*n*) direct-access cost isn't an issue if the length is limited to three elements), I'd use a *singly-linked list* instead. Create the list with two elements and, depending on the condition, append the third. This does *not* require any mutation: the 3-element list simply contains the unchanged 2-element list as a substructure.

Comment: Both interesting - I'm going with filter slice essentially as in the OP.  The linked list implementation is such an interesting idea, thank you!  I hadn't realized the option of using a linked list in an immutable environment,

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, I don't think arrays are the best solution simply because you know ahead of time that they contain *either* 2 values or 3 values depending on some condition. As such, I would model the problem as follows:

```
type alias Pair = (String, String)

type TokenState 
  = WithoutRefresh (Pair, Pair)
  | WithRefresh (Pair, Pair, Pair)

itemsToTokenState: String -> Date -> Maybe String -> TokenState
itemsToTokenState jwtKey jwtExpiry maybeRefreshToken =
  case maybeRefreshToken of
    Some refreshToken ->
      WithRefresh (("JWT_KEY", jwtKey), ("JWT_EXPIRES_KEY", toString jwtExpiry), ("REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY", refreshToken))

    None ->
      WithoutRefresh (("JWT_KEY", jwtKey), ("JWT_EXPIRES_KEY", toString jwtExpiry))
```

This way you are leveraging the type system more effectively, and could be improved on further by doing something more ergonomic than returning tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In this case I'm not 100% sure it will be 2 or 3 indefinitely into the future so I'm looking to implement a more generalized, FP-style solution.