# What is the special status of the 2-tuple?

Tags: haskell, tuples

Reading *Real World Haskell* and the [*Typeclassopedia*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) I get the impression that 2-tuples `(a,b)` can have very special roles in Haskell.

The first use that I came across is with `lookup` where we use a list of 2-tuples as a dictionary.

Then I also came across the fact that `((,) e)` is an instance of a functor (but no other n-tuple), which makes sense for example in the above example of `(key,value)`.

Now the most recent case - which is the one I actually want to ask about - is in chapter 4.3 of the Typeclassopedia. There it says that `((,) a)` is an instance of `Applicative` *if* `a` is a monoid. When do you actually make use of that? What are applications where you use the `Applicative` instance of `(a,b)`?

Comment: Oh, it gets worse! Pairs are also `Foldable`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36461185/126014

Comment: I don't think a 2-tuple itself has that much of a special status. The point is that usually 2-tuples are more "applicable" than 3-tuples. If you have a "dictionary", then you can obtain a list of key-values, a third value has no meaning here. The problem is: what to do with the third element.

Comment: Yes I see that, I just wonder what the `Applicative` instance would be useful for, as it requires the first argument be a `Monoid` instance.

Comment: The `((,) a)` applicative is equivalent to the [writer monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#t:Writer).

Comment: `fmap (*) ("a", 2) <*> ("b", 3) == ("ab", 6)` seems to be a reasonable behavior. The effect of an applicative tuple is that the last element is applied to the action, whereas the other elements have no relation to the last one (or to each other). They are merely appended.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ah I see, it seems that the `Applicative` instance doesn't make a lot of sense by itself, but in the context of this monad! Thank you

Comment: @flawr I wouldn't say that – basically all monads are also useful as mere applicatives. Just – for some reason I don't know – `Applicative` appears to be less intuitive and its use cases less evident than `Monad`.

Comment: The 2-tuple also has a `Comonad` and `ComonadEnv` instances (not int base) http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.3/docs/Control-Comonad.html#t:Comonad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing preventing us from writing an instance for triples or arbitrary n-tuples:

```
instance Functor ((,,) a b) where
  fmap f (x,y,z) = (x,y,f z)

instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Applicative ((,,) a b) where
  pure z              = (mempty,        mempty,          z)
  (a,b,f) <*> (x,y,z) = (a `mappend` x, b `mappend` y, f z)
```

Pairs aren't special therefore in the sense that you can implement the instance for any n-tuple. But since those instances have to be written somewhere, it begs the question how far we should go. For example, [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) instances are defined up to 5-tuples. It's certainly possible to write them for 10-tuples, but we're just copying boiler-plate code at that point.

That being said, **pairs are special** since their collection provide a natural way to describe a relation. One example is a dictionary, which relates  a term and its definition:

```
dictionary :: [(String, String)]
dictionary =
  [("cat", "animal that likes strings; not Strings, though")
  ,("dog", "animal that likes you; yes you")
  ,("foo", "a strange word used by programmers in examples")
  ]
```

The other way to show that relation (if the first parts of all pairs would be unique) would be

```
partialDictionaryEntry :: String -> String
```

if we limit the input domain to `"cat"`, `"dog"` and `"foo"`, or

```
dictionaryEntry :: String -> Maybe String
```

which is exactly what `\s -> lookup s dictionary` would be. And with pairs you can model any other n-tuple:

```
(a,b,z)   = ((a,b),z)
(a,b,c,z) = ((a,b,c),z) = (((a,b),c),z)
```

In that sense they are the smallest container that provides this functionality. We can build all other tuples types from pairs. Heck, theoretically we don't even need to write our `Applicative ((,,) a b)` instance, since it's already provided for `(,) (a,b)` due to  the `Monoid` instance.

That being said, why does it even have a `Applicative` instance? It's the simplest `Writer` implementation:

```
log :: (Show a) => a -> (String, a)
log x = (show x ++ "\n", x)

fivePlusThree = (+) <$> log 3 <*> log 5

main = do
  let (logs, result) = fivePlusThree
  putStrLn logs
  print result
```

```
3
5

8
```

This provides an easy way to add additional information to functions or values, although you will probably use `Writer` and its `writer` method, since they are more pleasant to use and provide a strict variant.