# Why in Haskell maximum (8,1) = 1?

Tags: haskell, max, foldable

I have just started learning Haskell. As I know `maximum` gives the max value for a list of integers. So, `maximum [2,5,7,1]` gives 7. But why by giving a tuple input does maximum always give the second element? E.g., `maximum (8,1)` gives 1. The same thing happens with `sum (8,1)`, `product (5,2)`, `minimum (4,5)`... all give the second element of the tuple. So, can anyone explain to a beginner why this happens?

Comment: For some additional context [Why does length return 1 for a tuple with 2 elements, and gives an error for a tuple with more elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460833/why-does-length-return-1-for-a-tuple-with-2-elements-and-gives-an-error-for-a-t)

Comment: A key concern is that for __tuples__, the types of the 2 elements are allowed to differ, so that (8, True) and (True, 8) are perfectly legal Haskell expressions. So there is no general way to define a maximum function that is both general and intuitively satisfying. For __lists__, all elements have to be of the same type, so [True, 8] is illegal, while maximum [8,1]  and maximum [1,8] are both legal and evaluate to 8, as you would intuitively expect.

Comment: Tuples aren't sequences in the sense that lists are. They are single values with multi-values tags. `(8, 1)` can be thought of as `1` with a tag of `8`; `(1,2,3,4,5)` can be thought of as a `5` with a four distinguished tags `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer**: for a 2-tuple, the `Foldable` instance takes (only) the second item into account. The `maximum` function will thus always return the second item of the 2-tuple.

Because a 2-tuple is an instance of `Foldable`. Indeed, it is [defined as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-339):

> ```
> instance Foldable ((,) a) where
>     foldMap f (_, y) = f y
>
>     foldr f z (_, y) = f y z
> ```

The `maximum` is in essence a foldr pattern. It is implemented as an equivalent of:

```
maximum = foldr1 max
```

Where `foldr1` is implemented as:

```
foldr1 f = fromMaybe (error "…") . foldr mf Nothing
    where mf x m = Just (case m of
                             Nothing -> x
                             Just y  -> f x y)
```

So that means that for a 2-tuple, it will be implemented as:

```
maximum (_, y) = fromMaybe (error "…") (mf y Nothing)
    where mf x m = Just (case m of
                             Nothing -> x
                             Just y  -> max x y)
```

So here we call `mf` with `y` (as `x` parameter), and `Nothing` as `m`. The `case … of …` this matches with `Nothing` and returns `x`. So the maximum for a 2-tuple is defined as:

```
maximum (_, y) = fromMaybe (error "…") (Just y)
```

and thus shorter:

```
-- maximum for a (a, b)
maximum (_, y) = y
```

Comment: Do you know why it's defined this way rather than taking both values into account?

Comment: @TheInnerLight: it can not take both values into account since the instance of a `Foldable` should be of kind `* -> *`, so an `instance Foldable (,)` would "crash", since that has as kind `* -> * -> *`.

Comment: @TheInnerLight what would be the maximum of this `('qwerty', 12345)`? Define the maximum of any tuple is actually senseless. But you can always define your own `maxTuple` function for tuples of type `(Int, Int)`

Comment: @TheInnerLight Because the types are different, in general. For instance `maximum ("hello", 4)` can not consider both elements. Here the type is `(,) String Int`, which is seen by `Foldable` as a container-like type `(,) String` which happens to have `Int` as its element. I'm not terribly convinced it was a good idea to allow `Foldable ((,) a)` in the libraries, but if we allow that, we have no type-safe option but to consider only the second component of the pairs.

Comment: @chi: me neither. TO be honest, I think a 2-tuple should probably not be a `Foldable`, since it creates a lot of confusion. Yes, we can see a 2-tuple as some sort of "value with a context" (that context is then the first item), but it will likely give a lot of confusion.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, I think the `Foldable` instance is good not because you would often want to fold a single-element container, but because it emphasizes the fact that a tuple is not just a minor variation on a list. The fact that `maximum (8,1)` doesn't return `8` should force you to stop and ask yourself why you have a tuple in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure where that metaphor is going. My point is, if you think passing a tuple to `maximum` is a good idea, rethink why you are using a tuple. Tuples are foldable, just not in the way lists are foldable, and that's neither good nor bad, just *different*.

Comment: @chepner If the goal is to discourage me from using `maximum (x,y)`, a type error would be the most effective means, IMO. Unrelated: I wonder how many packages on hackage rely on such a weird instance, after it being in `base` for 5? years.

Comment: My goal *isn't* to discourage you from using `maximum (x,y)`; it's to discourage you from using `(x, y)` in a context where you think comparing `x` and `y` to each other will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples in Haskell are not multi-valued containers like they are in, say, Python. Rather, they are closer to *single*-valued containers like `Maybe a` or `Either b a`: a value with a context. While both `Maybe` and `Either` carry the concept of possibly no value (`Either` simply providing more information than `Maybe` about the lack of a value), a tuple carries the context of information about the value itself.

A value like `(8, 1`) does not *contain* two values `8` and `1`. Rather, `8` is *part of* a container that contains a `1`.

As such, tuples are foldable, even if doing so seems trivial. Reducing a value of type `(a, b)` to a value of `b` simply has to return the value of type `b`, without worrying about what to do with the other values of type `b`, because there *aren't* any.

```
>>> maximum (Just 5)
5
>>> minimum (Just 5)
5

>>> maximum (Right 5)
5
>>> minimum (Right 5)
5

>>> maximum (True, 5)
5
>>> minimum (True, 5)
5
```

Such functions are *total* with tuples, though, as compared to `Maybe` or `Either`:

```
>>> maximum Nothing
*** Exception: maximum: empty structure
>>> maximum (Left 5)
*** Exception: maximum: empty structure
```

No matter how many types the tuple contains, all but the right-most one will fixed for any given instance of `Foldable`.

```
-- Actual instance for (a, b)
instance Foldable ((,) a) where
    foldMap f (_, y) = f y
    foldr f z (_, y) = f y z


-- Instance for (a, b, c) if you wanted it
instance Foldable ((,,) a b) where
    foldMap f (_, _, y) = f y
    foldr f z (_, _, y) = f y z
```