# Why `minimum (1, 2)` returns 2 in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Why `minimum (1, 2)` is 2 in Haskell?

My test result in GHCi,

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> minimum (1, 2)
2
```

Shouldn't it return 1?

Comment: Minimum is a function that works on lists. You're probably looking for `min`. That said, I'm not sure what funkiness is going on here, probably some identity for tuples as lists or something. I remember a question a few days ago that was similar I think.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87re_yIQMDw (FWIW, I think it _is_ a [Wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).)

Comment: [Related: `Why is toList (1, 2) == [2]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113469/why-is-tolist-1-2-2/36133838)

Comment: Note `minimum (True, 3)` also type checks, and evaluates to `3`. This is because the foldable instance is `Foldable ((,) a)`, so only the second component matters. Indeed, we can't take the minimum between two components which could be of two different types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `minimum` is

```
 (Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
```

The [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-311) instance for pairs refers only to the second element of the pair, which you can see with `toList`:

```
toList (1,2)
> [2]
```

the minimum element in that collection is `2`.

Comment: ... and it couldn't include both components in the list since `toList ("hello", 2)` also type checks, but `["hello", 2]` does not.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this behaviour is twofold:

- Since the [FTP](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude), the functions like `minimum` or `length` (these are [catamorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism), i.e. functions which simmer down a container structure to a single value) don't just operate on lists anymore, but on general [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) instances. That's very useful, for instance you can directly calculate the minimum of an array, map or trie without first having to convert it to a list. (Prior to the FTP, your expression would have just been a type error, because the argument is not a list but a tuple.)
- Tuples are functors, and specifically, they are functors *in the second argument*. This allows doing stuff like

  ```
  Prelude> fmap (+1) <$> [("Bla",2), ("blub",3)]
  [("Bla",3),("blub",4)]
  ```

  That it's the second argument arises from the fact that `(a,b)` is actually syntactic sugar for `((,) a) b`, i.e. we're dealing with the `((,)a)` functor here. This is *the only possible way* you can make a Haskell tuple functor instance!
  IMHO, having that instance at all isn't really a good feature though<sup>†</sup>, because tuples are supposed to be in a sense *symmetric* between there elements. Well, Haskell tuples aren't symmetric, they are “containers containing one polymorphic element”, namely the second one.

That wouldn't too bad by itself, but tuples also have a `Foldable` instance: once you decide that a tuple is a container for the second element specifically, it's natural to also want to run catamorphisms on it. They're not very exciting catamorphisms, working only ever on one element, and in particular it's really confusing that even if the first element has the same type, the catamorphism just ignores it. But oh well, here we are.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>The proper way to write the above is IMO `second (+1) <$> [("Bla",2), ("blub",3)]`, using [`second` from `Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second), which is equivalent to `fmap` on tuples but avoids the confusion between the two elements. (Also, it's more general, but not in a way that would make a difference for most applications: it can be used with general *arrows*, not just with functions.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When you look to the [documentation](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=minimum) you will find out that minimum can have various inputs (in the sense of argument's type).

In your case you want to apply a `list` to the minimum function to get a minimal element, so try

```
minimum [1,2]
```